# Type mismatch while trying to sort a collection

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot for the life of my while I'm getting a type mismatch while sorting a collection that already has the object in it.

Can someone please explain why the error happens, below is the code I'm using to sort the collection.

```
Private Sub SortItems(combinedItems As Collection)
    Dim counter As Integer, _
        counter2 As Integer, _
        temp As Variant, _
        tempColleciton As New Collection, _
        currentSortItem As SortItem, _
        nextSortItem As SortItem, _
        sortDirection As SortType

        sortDirection = SortOrder

    For counter = 1 To combinedItems.Count - 1
        For counter2 = counter + 1 To combinedItems.Count
            Set currentSortItem = combinedItems(counter)
            Set nextSortItem = combinedItems(counter2)
            If currentSortItem.Key > nextSortItem.Key Then
                combinedItems.Remove counter2

                If sortDirection = Ascending Then
                    combinedItems.Add nextSortItem, nextSortItem, counter 'error occurs here if Ascending
                Else
                    combinedItems.Add nextSortItem, nextSortItem, After:=counter 'error occurs here if Decending
                End If

            End If
        Next counter2
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use an object as the key in a collection?

```
combinedItems.Add nextSortItem, nextSortItem, counter
```

Try using:

```
combinedItems.Add nextSortItem, nextSortItem.Key, counter
```

Comment: I am, is that the reason that this is happening?

Comment: Yes. The key in a collection should be a string expression

Comment: okay, thank you what do you recommend to when the key is always a double?

Comment: @3xGuy, try using `cstr()` to convert the `double` to a `string`. Something like `cstr(nextSortItem.Key)`.

Comment: Why are you sorting a collection?  You should only be sorting the keys by building a second collection which maps the keys to the index in the first collection  The sorting/indexing/adding/removing of items to the collection would be best encapsulated in a class.